# How can I spy an active accessibility combobox in blue prism? I want to open the combobox and select an element from it

Tags: combobox, rpa, blueprism

So I have a combobox for the user to select whether he is an old customer or a new customer. With my process I was able to identify the combobox as an AA element so my process is now able to identify the combobox and click on it when it runs. But the problem starts when I need to select the "new customer" option after opening the combobox. I am unable to identify the option either as a HTML element nor an AA element.Because of this,the process is not able to select an option and throws an error.

What I tried:

I tried an alternative where I added a navigate stage for just the dropdown/combobox and in the properties for this stage I added "select item" as the action and entered the name for the option which in this case is "new customer" along with the item position. This does not work either and throws an error saying "select item" cannot be used for AA whose role is "static text".

P.S: I checked the attributes for the combobox and unchecked the role attribute but that did not work.

Comment: My first question would be why use AA to find a HTML combo box, when you can use HTML spying? This mode is better used for HTML objects and here you can choose either Inputs or Position.

To change from AA to HTML press ALT while your spy tool is up. Remember to attach to your browser window before trying to spy. If attaching seems to give problems, go to a blank page and attach from there as javascripts can make BP malfunction on HTML spying. (Seen it a few times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ComboBox is standard HTML Combo Box(Element Type) in Application Modeller. But in `Navigation` step I use `Select Item` as `Action` and in `Inputs` section I use `Item Position` as a Number.

Where 0 is first position in combobox, blank. 1 is the first position, in your case it would be "new customer" and 2 would be "old customer".

It works fine in my case.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mode html on the combobox to click then send down key in global key event to choose what you want.