# Blueprism: how to scroll down a list?

Tags: scroll, blueprism, rpa

I have a menu button. When this menu button is clicked, a list of options with overflow-scroll property shows. I want to click on an item on this list. This item comes into the viewport after scrolling through the list. How do I implement this scrolling functionality in blueprism? It seems I need this item in the viewport to be able to click it (which results in a pop-up). I am using Accessibility mode to spy on the list and on the item I want to access.

Comment: What kind of application is this regarding? Web? Windows app?

Comment: It is a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was working whit ComboBox I came up whit that kind of solution.

In Navigate step as Action you Select Item, then in Input section you will be able to point which position do you want to choose and you are doing it by inputing the numer of that item on the list.
Where first position is 0 etc...

Here is my answer to combobox question: 
[How can I spy an active accessibility combobox in blue prism? I want to open the combobox and select an element from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944899/how-can-i-spy-an-active-accessibility-combobox-in-blue-prism-i-want-to-open-the/46315584#46315584)

Hope it will help, right know I dont have accses to BP so I cant be sure.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing this. I saw your answer :) Thanks!

Comment: For those interested, another way that I found would bring the item into the viewport is to use a navigation stage for the item, and select focus as the action.